# Incorrect result is returned in the callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

Hi I want to combine the two collections and send the combined result. I did the following. I am using the mongoclient.

```
> module.exports = function (context, req) {
> 
>     //making the connection
>     var response;
>     //check for the request method
> 
>     if (req.method !== 'GET') {
>         response = {
>             status: 500,
>             body: {
>                 "code": 500,
>                 "message": "Invalid request. Please check the request method or parameter"
>             },
>             headers: {
>                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>             }
>         }
>         context.done(null, response);
>         return;
>     } //end of if
> 
>     mongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function (err, client) {
>         assert.equal(null, err);
>         var database = client.db(databaseConfig.mLabDbName);
>         var response;
>         var getUserIdParams = req.query.userId
>         var index = req.query.index;
>         var noOfResults = mapResultsWithIndex(index)
> 
> 
>         getSubByUId(database, context, getUserIdParams, function (res, err) {
> 
>             // console.log("response from the callback", res)
> 
> 
>         getForms(database, context, res, function (result) {
>                 console.log("response from secondcallback", result)
> 
> 
>                 //closing the connection
>                 client.close();
> 
>                 if (err) {
>                     console.log("an error in getting the result");
>                     response = {
>                         status: 500,
>                         body: {
>                             code: 500,
>                             message: "Error in getting the forms"
>                         },
>                         headers: {
>                             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>                         }
>                     }
>                 } //end of error
>                 else {
>                     if (result.length > 0) {
>                         console.log("got the data");
>                         response = {
>                             status: 200,
>                             body: {
>                                 code: 200,
>                                 result: result
>                             },
>                             headers: {
>                                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>                             }
>                         }
>                     } else {
>                         console.log("did not get the data");
>                         response = {
>                             status: 204,
>                             body: {
>                                 code: 204,
>                                 message: "No submissions found for the user id"
>                             },
>                             headers: {
>                                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
> 
>                 }
> 
>                  context.done(null, response)
>             })
>            
> 
>         }) //end of subId
> 
>     }) //closing mongodb connection }; //closing function
>
```

My main functions are:

```
var getForms = function (db, context, array, callback) {
    let newArray = [];
    // console.log("array uuuuu", array)
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        db.collection('forms').find({_id:ObjectID(array[i].formId)}).toArray(function (err, res) {
            console.log("rskkkk",res.length)
            res.forEach(doc => {
                newArray.push({
                    "subId": array[i]._id,
                    "formId": array[i].formId,
                    "userId": array[i].userId,
                    "formDescription": array[i].formDescription,
                    "formFields": array[i].formFields,
                    "createdAt": array[i].createdAt,
                    "data": array[i].data,
                    "imageformedarray": doc.imageUploadedarray
                })

            })
            callback(newArray);
            console.log("new array is", newArray.length);

        })


    }



}

var getSubByUId = function (db, context, getUserIdParams, callback) {
    let arr = [],
        type;
    var getSubmissions = db.collection('user-submission').find({
        userId: getUserIdParams
    });
    getSubmissions.toArray(function (err, res) {
        res.forEach(doc => {
            var value = doc.createdAt
            if (doc.hasOwnProperty("updatedAt")) {
                value = doc.updatedAt
            }
            if ((typeof (doc.formFields)) === "string") {
                console.log("string")
                type = JSON.parse(doc.formFields)
                // type = doc.data().formFields
            } else {
                type = doc.formFields
            }

            arr.push({
                "subId": doc._id,
                "formId": doc.formId,
                "userId": doc.userId,
                "formDescription": doc.formDescription,
                "formFields": type,
                "createdAt": value,
                "data": doc

            })
        });
        // console.log("arr is", arr);
        callback(arr, err)

    })

}
```

I want to return the entire array, but it only returns the result in the first loop. When i moved this callback of the **getForms** where it is present, it returns the result with null value.
    Please help.

Comment: I am not familiar with mongodb. But I wanted to ask whether do you see all the elements in the array before  ```callback(newArray)``` and how does the callback look like? may be add all elements to the new array and consider calling the callback after completing the loop? just a thought.

Comment: @Bala the **newArray** becomes **null** if I call it after the completion of the loop.

Comment: can you also post the callback function here? we have 2 functions getForms and getSubByUId. but we are interested in getSubByUId? based on the description looks like the issue is only with getForms?

Comment: calling `context.done` terminates the function execution. You can't call that in a loop.

Comment: @ahemlsayed agreed,then how am I supposed to return the value? Is their any other better approach as I am not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the callback for the `getForms` method when you iterate the array with the for loop. This is passing control to the callback which is then handling the `context.done` for the function which will always output the first element.

As is, this code will also result in multiple calls to context.done, which should be only called once per function execution.
Keep in mind that definition for context.done is `context.done([err],[propertyBag])` which expects an object as output.

For further references check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node

In addition to the that set the `functions.json` output binding to:

```
{
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out",
  "name": "$return"
}
```

Now if you move `callback(newArray)` outside of the `for loop` you should see the expected results.

Comment: the code is working as you described that is it is calling `context.done` multiple times and for the first time when it calls context.done() it returns the response.                           Now if I move `callback(newArray)` outside the for loop, this **newArray  becomes null**, and returns the null value.

Comment: I've improved the answer with the `functions.json` settings that will allow you to consume directly from the output of the context call.

Comment: I have already added the `$return` but still facing the same issue.

Comment: The `$return` allows you to return a value directly from the function, otherwise it uses the property bag. The default config is to use `res` so you that you could be writing `context.res.body= [1,2]` then `context.done(null)` and the output will be `[1,2]` which may map better to your existing code